# javascript Date.now() continue to stack

Tags: javascript, image, date, src

I want to get the last picture from ipCamera, my function is like this.
basically, after one image load. then immediately startover loop().  I prefer not to use AJAX.

```
  var toggle= function(_imageUrl  ) { //refresh include and adjust
      var img = document.getElementById('image');

      var updater = function(){
          var time = Date.now();

          var loop = function() {
            ImageURL = _imageUrl + '&' + time;
            console.log(time)
            img.setAttribute("src", imageURL);
            ImageURL = ''; //set the image.src to empty
            img.addEventListener('load', function() {
              setTimeout(updater ,100)
            }, false);
          };
          loop();
      }
      updater();
  };
```

This function works fine, but apparently, the Date.now() continue to stack by each loading time. Here is the result of console.log(time);

```
 First Loop:
     1417935798237
 Second loop:
     1417935798237
     1417935798925
 ThirdLoop (as it took longer to load), thus the time stack more
    1417935798925
    1417935800057
    1417935800057
    1417935801226
    1417935801227
    1417935801228
    1417935801228
```

The function has to evaluate more item by each loop,  before rendering the last image, in the end it still deliver the last image, but by the 20th loop. the list is immense

> Question:
>   1. what happened? 
>   2. How to set Date.now() to only one last timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you call `loop` another eventListener is added because of the `img.addEventListener` call.   Your eventListener will be called when the image's url changes ( causing the browser to reload the image ).  That eventListener should only be added once.  Move that outside of the `loop` function.

```
  var toggle= function(_imageUrl  ) { //refresh include and adjust
          var img = document.getElementById('image');

          img.addEventListener('load', function() {
            setTimeout(loop ,100)
          }, false);

          var loop = function() {
            var time = Date.now();
            imageURL = _imageUrl + '&' + time;
            console.log(time)
            img.setAttribute("src", imageURL);
            imageURL = ''; //set the image.src to empty

          };
          loop();
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are reusing the same `img` object in each loop, you keep adding more and more event listeners to it each time through the loop and thus when it loads, it doesn't just call your loop once, but N times.

Probably what you want to do is to move the adding of the event listener to outside the loop so it is only added once.

You will have to test this code carefully in whatever older browsers you want to support because a few years ago, I found some reliability issues with triggering `load` events more than one time on the same `img` object.

Also, you have references in your code to both `_imageURL` and `imageURL`.  Are those supposed to be different?

Comment: The OP could also create the function as a function declaration, then assign it by reference and it should only be added once no matter how many times it's assigned through *addEventListener*. But putting the assignment outside the loop is better. ;-)

Comment: i create ImageUrl, and set it to empty immediately after src=ImageUrl, to prevent further download.

Comment: @jfriend00 I sincerely apologize, I was confused because my console.log is mixed, but the answer from Alex below is correct.